# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image on this specific image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load this specific image. And I get this error. I wonder what's wrong with this image why Pillow cannot process the image. If I load the image in the browser, it works fine. Other images works fine.

this is a snippet of the error:
`raise UnidentifiedImageError(error PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x101c323b0`

this is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests

url = 'https://files.23point5.com/file?path=/artist-library/a39f0470-3cfe-4d5d-8288-ebf788c085c6.png'
element_image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
print(element_image)
```

Comment: Try looking at the first 20 bytes of the thing you are passing to `Image.open()`

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `print(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw[:20])` should do the trick.